# When is Hydra going to be completed?

Tags: transaction, cardano-foundation

I’m impressed with all the work that you have done. I’ve been amazed by Hydra, and everything you continue to do with Cardano.

Comment: Not really an appropriate question, see the help for guidance.

Comment: Questions of timing are rarely appropriate for StackExchange, they are more suitable for the Cardano Reddit Forums.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because the questions about the future of Cardano can't be effectively addressed on this site and would be better addressed directly to the Cardano Team on their [forum](https://forum.cardano.org/). This site is not operated by the Cardano organization.

Answer (score 1):

We will see some form of Hydra in action by end of 2021 or the first quarter of 2022. Charles mentioned a couple of times that a separate team is always working on it and will try to release it sooner than previously planned.